# Using self.image with a list of lists that contain JPEG files

Tags: python, fpdf

I am trying to show several images in a pdf by using FPDF. These images are saved in a list of lists that contain object type JPEG. I want to use the self.image function for each image inside the list of lists but I'm getting the error: " TypeError:unhashable type: 'JpegImageFile' ".

I have also tried to iterate throughout the list but it says the JPEGFileType is not iterable. How can I have the pictures seen in the pdf?

This is the function used for the self.image function from FPDF. The *all_pics* variable contains the list of lists with all the images in it. The *num* variable indicates the list inside the list where I want to take every image in it.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

class FPDF(FPDF):
    def print_images (self, num, all_pics):
        for img in all_pics[num]:
            self.image(img, x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')

def main_pdf(num, all_pics, bearing_data):  
    
    if num != 'Select number':
        export = st.button("Export Report")
        if export:
            pdf=FPDF()
            for i in range(num):
                pdf.print_images(i, all_pics)
```

This is the Traceback I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'JpegImageFile'

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dksojfab\Anaconda3\envs\Julias_works\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "form_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    conv.main_pdf(num, all_pics, bearing_info)
File "C:\Users\dksojfab\OneDrive - Alfa Laval\Documents\Python Scripts\convert_to_pdf.py", line 106, in main_pdf
    pdf.print_images(i, all_pics)
File "C:\Users\dksojfab\OneDrive - Alfa Laval\Documents\Python Scripts\convert_to_pdf.py", line 94, in print_images
    self.image(img, x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')
File "C:\Users\dksojfab\Anaconda3\envs\Julias_works\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dksojfab\Anaconda3\envs\Julias_works\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 960, in image
    if not name in self.images:
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please show all the code that produces this issue, especially the entire declaration of the class that contains this `print_images` method?

Comment: Are you sure `all_pics` is a 2d list? Looks to me that `all_pics[num]` isn't a list but a `JPEGFileType`

Comment: @josh-stackoverflow if it's a "JPEGFileType" how can I access it then? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Well first check the contents of `all_pics` - I'm not sure how you've generated it and you've provided little context as @wkl mentioned. You seem to believe that it is a 2d list and we cannot comment on why that is the case.

Comment: The documentation for `FPDF` says that the `image()` method takes its first parameter as a path or URL, which I imagine it is expecting to be a string. It looks like it is using that string as a key to a `dict`.